# Output in R, Avoid Writing "[1]"

Tags: r

I use `print` to output from a function in R, for example:

```
print("blah blah blah")
```

This outputs

```
[1] "blah blah blah"
```

To the console.  How can I avoid the `[1]` and the quotes?

Comment: Use `cat` or `message`.  See
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102643/whats-a-prettier-way-to-print-info-with-r

Comment: Thanks aaron, dason, and alex.  I spent too long looking for printf

Comment: Feel free to upvote answers you have found helpful and to select whichever answer you feel is the best.

Comment: FYI, The R equivalent of `printf` is `sprintf`

Comment: https://jangorecki.gitlab.io/data.table/library/data.table/html/print.data.table.html

Answer (score 40):

Use `cat("Your string")` (type `?cat` to see help page) to output concatenated objects to standard output.

Comment: You probably want `cat("Your string\n")` since `print("Your string")` automatically adds line breaks

Answer (score 23):

`message` is probably the best function to replace `print` for your needs.  `cat` is also a good function to look at but `message` will print a new line for you as well.  It is also better to use since it is easier to suppress the output from `message` than it is to suppress the output from `cat`.

If you just want to remove the quotes but don't mind the [1] printing then you could use the `quote=FALSE` option of `print`.

---

Edit: As noted in the comments, `message`  isn't the same as a call to `print` as it sends the output to a different connection.  Using `cat` will do what you want as others have noted but you'll probably want to add a new line on after your message.

Example

```
cat("This is a message\n") # You'll want to add \n at the end
```

Comment: Don't use `message`. It sends its output to the `stderr` connection, as opposed to `cat` (and `print`) which use `stdout`, and this can throw you if you ever decide to redirect your output, eg with `sink`. `message` is really more akin to `warning`, in that it's meant for diagnostics and warnings.

Comment: Ah.  Thank you.  I forgot about that.  I usually use it just to print messages inside of functions either while debugging or to display some sort of progress check on long functions.  I like it because then you can use suppressMessages easily (and I prefer using this as opposed to sink).  But you're right and print and messages aren't exactly interchangeable.  Using cat is probably a better choice.

Comment: It always depends on what you really mean. If you mean, yes, just print the text, I want to see it and nobody can stop me, you can use `cat()`; if you mean this is a message (should not go to `stdout`), `message()` is the correct choice. I believe many people are abusing `cat()`, especially in package startup messages. This is pretty annoying actually, because it is difficult to suppress the messages. The difference in the output from `cat()` and `message()` looks subtle, but there is a big difference behind the scene.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to get rid of the `[1]` only, but preserve the line breaks:

```
string_vector <- c('some', 'words', 'in', 'a', 'vector')
paste(string_vector, collapse = '\n') %>% cat()
```

produces:

```
some
words
in
a
vector
```

Answer (score 3):

Messing around with `print.data.frame` may sometimes be useful for custom print methods.

```
print(data.frame("message" = "", row.names = "blah blah blah"))
#                message
# blah blah blah  

print(data.frame("message" = "blah blah blah", row.names = ""))
#         message
#  blah blah blah
```