# date output without quotes and line number

Tags: r

I want to output today's date without quotes and without line numbers.
How do I get rid of the line number? [1] looks like row 1 of a matrix

```
R code:
noquote(as.character(Sys.Date()))
[1] 2019-11-21
```

Sys.Date() Makes the problem a little different than usual.
Unless code is exactly as I am giving in the solution
Sys.Date will be output with a "". I tried using a 
semicolon at the end of the line to prevent that from
happening but was not successful.

My cursor is messed up when I use the following suggested command.

```
Output:
> cat(as.character(Sys.Date()))
2019-11-21>
```

Thanks. MM

Comment: `cat(as.character(Sys.Date()))`

Comment: That's just how R prints information into the console. It isn't attached to the data or anything, it's just a way of making the output more readable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Output in R, Avoid Writing "\[1\]"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9137798/output-in-r-avoid-writing-1)

Comment: Sys.Date is very particular about being printed out. Thank you for your reply.  MM

Comment: cat approach messed up R > 
 (the data input character). That is why I don't use it. >cat(as.character(Sys.Date())) 
2019-11-21> cat(as.character(Sys.Date()))

Answer (score 1):

I thought I had tried them all but I hadn't.
I like my work to have identifying information such as name, date, etc.

```
writeLines function is the answer.
writeLines(noquote(as.character(Sys.Date())))
```

MM