# When does the object returned by invisible() cease to be invisible?

Tags: r, language-lawyer

`?invisible` says

> Return a (temporarily) invisible copy of an object.

That parenthetical implies that the invisibility will not last forever, but I can't find anything that explains when it goes away.  I'm particularly wondering about constructs like this one (from [this old answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13023274/how-to-do-printf-in-r/13023329#13023329)):

```
printf <- function(...) invisible(print(sprintf(...)))
```

where the outer `invisible` is *probably* unnecessary (because `print` already marked its return value invisible).  `withVisible()` reports that this function's return value is invisible either way, but I don't know whether that is guaranteed by the language, or just the way it happens to work in the current implementation.

Comment: it looks the C code simply returns its argument.  So, by temporary, it may just mean anything returned from within the `invisible` call won't print, but something like `printf <- function(...) +invisible(1); printf(1)` will still print `1`, whereas `printf <- function(...) invisible(1); printf(1)` wont

Answer (score 2):

By trial and error:

```
# invisible
withVisible(invisible())$visible
[1] FALSE

### passing the invisible value through a function seems to
# preserve the invisibility
withVisible(identity(invisible()))$visible
[1] FALSE

# the <- operator just returns its arguments, so it confirms the above
withVisible(i <- invisible())$visible
[1] FALSE
# but the assigned value is no longer invisible
withVisible(i)$visible
[1] TRUE

### passing an invisible value as argument keeps the invisibility
f <- function(x) withVisible(x)$visible
f(1)
[1] TRUE
f(invisible(1))
[1] FALSE

### every other operation seems to cancel the invisibility.
# e.g. assigning an invisible value cancels the it
i <- invisible()
withVisible(i)$visible
[1] TRUE

withVisible(invisible(1) + 1)$visible
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This is useful information, but I am really hoping for an answer from the *language specification* (to the extent R has one) rather than the observed behavior of the implementation.  In other words, we can see what it *does*, but is that what it is *supposed to do*, and will it stay that way?