# Another function useful than Elbow in finding k-clusters

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, k-means

I try to find the appropriate k clusters for k-means method in Machine Learning. I used Elbow method, but it time consuming and high complexity. Can anyone tell me another method to replace it. Thanks so much

Comment: http://www.web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/gap.pdf

Comment: *All* these stats tend to only work when the data is very nicely behaved, barely on real data. The reason is simple: they are sensitive to *preprocessing*, too. The bottom line is, unfortunately, that you cannot use them to automate clustering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A metric that you can use to evaluate the result of a clustering is the [silhouette coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette_(clustering)). This value basically computes:

```
silhouette coefficient = 1 - (intra-cluster cohesion) / (inter-cluster separation)
```

The value ranges from -1 to +1, but generally you want values closer to 1.0. So if you run a clustering algorithm (e.g. k-means or hierarchical clustering) to produce 3 clusters, you can call a silhouette library to compute a silhouette coefficient value, e.g. 0.50. If you run your algorithm again to produce 4 clusters, you may compute another silhouette coefficient value, e.g. 0.55. You could then conclude that 4 clusters is a better clustering because it has a higher silhouette coefficient.

Below is an example data set where I've created three different clusters in 2-D space using R. NOTE: Real-world data will never look this clean with such obvious separation between clusters. Even simple data like Fisher's Iris data set has overlap between labelled clusters.

[image]

You can then use R's silhouette library to compute the silhouette coefficient. (More information can be found [at the STHDA website](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/determining-the-optimal-number-of-clusters-3-must-known-methods-unsupervised-machine-learning#average-silhouette-method).) Below are plots of the silhouette information. The one metric that you want is in the lower-left corner, which says "Average silhouette width: xxx". That value is the average of all the horizontal bars.

Here is the silhouette coefficient for K=2 clusters.

```
plot(silhouette(kmeans(df, centers=2)$cluster, dist(df)))
```

[image]

Here is the silhouette coefficient for K=3 clusters.

```
plot(silhouette(kmeans(df, centers=3)$cluster, dist(df)))
```

[image]

Here is the silhouette coefficient for K=4 clusters.

```
plot(silhouette(kmeans(df, centers=4)$cluster, dist(df)))
```

[image]

From looking at the silhouette coefficients, you can conclude that K=3 clusters is the best clustering because it has the highest silhouette coefficient.

You can find the best K value programmatically by simply sweeping through the multiple K value candidates (e.g. between 2 and 10) while keeping track of the highest silhouette coefficient found. Below I've done just that while also building a plot of silhouette coefficient (y-axis) vs. K (x-axis). The output says:

> Best Silhouette coefficient=0.888926 occurred at k=3

[image]

```R
library(cluster) # for silhouette
library(ggplot2) # for ggplot
library(scales) # for pretty_breaks


# Create sample 2-D data set with clusters around the points (1,1), (2,4), and (3,1)
x<- c(rnorm(n=25, mean=1,sd=.1), rnorm(n=25,mean=2,sd=.1),rnorm(n=25,mean=3,sd=.2))
y<- c(rnorm(n=25, mean=1,sd=.1), rnorm(n=25,mean=4,sd=.1),rnorm(n=25,mean=1,sd=.2))

df <- data.frame(x=x, y=y)

xMax <- max(x)
yMax <- max(y)
print(ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + xlim(0, max(xMax, yMax)) + ylim(0, max(xMax,yMax)))


# Use the Iris data set.
#df <- subset(iris, select=-c(Species))
#df <- scale(df)


# Run through multiple candidate values of K clusters.

xValues <- c() # Holds the kvalues (x-axis)
yValues <- c() # Holds the silhouette coefficient values (y-axis)
bestKValue <- 0
bestSilhouetteCoefficient <- 0

kSequence <- seq(2, 5)

for (kValue in kSequence) {

    xValues <- append(xValues, kValue)
    kmeansResult <- kmeans(df, centers=kValue, nstart=5)
    silhouetteResult <- silhouette(kmeansResult$cluster, dist(df))
    silhouetteCoefficient <- mean(silhouetteResult[,3])
    yValues <- append(yValues, silhouetteCoefficient)

    if (silhouetteCoefficient > bestSilhouetteCoefficient) {
        bestSilhouetteCoefficient <- silhouetteCoefficient
        bestKValue <- kValue
    }
}

# Create a dataframe for ggplot to plot the accumulated silhouette values.
dfSilhouette <- data.frame(k=xValues, silhouetteCoefficient=yValues)

# Create the ggplot line plot for silhouette coefficient.
silhouettePlot<- ggplot(data=dfSilhouette, aes(k)) +
    geom_line(aes(y=silhouetteCoefficient)) +
    xlab("k") +
    ylab("Average silhouette width") +
    ggtitle("Average silhouette width") +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=pretty_breaks(n=20)) 

print(silhouettePlot)

printf <- function(...) cat(sprintf(...))
printf("Best Silhouette coefficient=%f occurred at k=%d", bestSilhouetteCoefficient, bestKValue )
```

Note that I've used the printf function from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13023274/how-to-do-printf-in-r).

A related question to yours is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376075/cluster-analysis-in-r-determine-the-optimal-number-of-clusters).

Comment: Thanks for response. It's helpful